# How to create a case activity using the API?

Tags: api

I want to create an activity inside a case. I can create a case using `$result = civicrm_api3('case', 'create', $params);` But how do I pass the case id in the api which creates an Activity. To create Activity I am using: `civicrm_api('Activity', 'create', $activityparam);`

Comment: Can you edit the question and put the code (including activityparam)

Answer (score 5):

The param you are looking for is `case_id` which can be used like:

```
civicrm_api3('Activity', 'create', array(
  'subject' => 'Hello',
  'case_id' => 123,
  ...
));
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. Where should have I looked for to find that key 'case_id' ?

Comment: @MSivani click the checkbox to mark this answer correct :).

Comment: Hmm you're right that param seems a bit hidden. I think it needs to be added to the `_civicrm_api3_activity_create_spec` function so it will be visible in the api explorer. Here I've [created a PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5923) to add it.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to create an Activity because we already have a table called civicrm_case_activity. Which links the case Id against the new activity created and you can also view the activity against CiviCase Dashboard. I guess this helps!!!

Comment: Not sure if you are considering the need that I want to create an Activity using API in my custom module. I do not see any parameter key in civicrm_api('Activity', 'create', $activityparam);  to pass the case id.

Comment: yes, you cannot pass case Id while creating the activity but you can create an activity and make a entry in civicrm_case_activity which will link the created activity again the case Id.